# Suppose a group $G$ splits as $A \ast_H B$ and $G > K \geq H$. Does $G$ also split over $K$?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be finitely generated, and consider a chain of subgroups $G > K \geq H$. We say that $G$ *splits over* $H$ if $G$ acts without inversions on a simplicial tree $T$ with some edge stabilised by $H$, and this action is minimal (no proper invariant sub tree).

Suppose that $G$ does indeed split over $H$. Can we conclude that $G$ splits over $K$?

I feel like I've seen before that this is true, for relatively trivial reasons. However, I'm struggling to reproduce this and now I'm starting to doubt it's truth.

There's a chance I may be missing some important hypotheses, but any comments are appreciated. Thanks

---

Quick edit: Upon reflection, a possible necessary condition on $K$ could be that $K$ is a co-dimension 1 subgroup of $G$.

Edit 2: Added the condition that this action be minimal.

Comment: You might want to add the assumption that $G$ acts minimally (ie with no proper invariant sub trees), otherwise this is true for any group $G$ and any subgroup $K$ (independent of whether $G$ splits over $H$). To see this, consider the splitting $G\ast_KK$.

Comment: Good point, have done so.

Comment: The action for the splitting over $K$ should also be minimal to avoid the answer being vacuously true